AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance', but it reverted with a custom error
it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async function () {
      const initialOwnerBalance = await polishToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
      // Try to send 1 token from addr1 (0 tokens) to owner (1000000 tokens).
      // `require` will evaluate false and revert the transaction.
      await expect(
        polishToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
      ).to.be.revertedWith("ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

      // Owner balance shouldn't have changed.
      expect(await polishToken.balanceOf(owner.address)).to.equal(
        initialOwnerBalance
      );
    });

Here is the code. Keeps throwing an error:
 Transactions
      ✔ Should transfer tokens between accounts
      1) Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens
      ✔ Should update balances after transfers


  5 passing (702ms)
  1 failing

  1) PolishToken contract
       Transactions
         Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens:
     AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance', but it reverted with a custom error
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\PolishToken.js:55:7)

This has been driving me nuts for 2 days. I can't find anyone else with the same issue and I cant find the issue. Seems it should work.
I even tried changing it to "not enough tokens" out of desparation. What am I missing?

Assuming you are using Openzeppelin version 5.x contracts. The error handling has been changed from require statement to custom errors.
Here is version 4.9 with ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance - ERC20 4.9
And here is version 5 with custom error - ERC20 5.0
So your test should be
await expect(
        polishToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
  polishToken,
  "ERC20InsufficientBalance").
withArgs(from, fromBalance, 1);

Please check the hardhat doc once for the custom Errors, if face any issue.

This fixed it. Thank you so much.

Cool, you can mark it as solved then, by clicking on the check mark near my answer.
